# LEFT JOIN breaks WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql

I've recently been required to input more information from my database and I've just LEFT JOIN to help me, it works almost perfectly(it does actually get the right field from the other table) but my WHERE clause is nullified giving the user access to both tables without the restriction of my where clause.

MySQL doesn't crap out any errors, so I'm assuming it's something to do with my where clause or something happened in the join.

```
SELECT * FROM students 
LEFT JOIN courses ON students.appliedforCourse = courses.idNumber 
WHERE 
    students.telephone LIKE '%$var' 
    OR students.email LIKE '%$var' 
    OR students.address like'%$var%' 
    OR (CONCAT(students.firstName,' ',students.lastName) LIKE '%$var%')
    AND addedBy ='$userid'
LIMIT $s,limit
```

Comment: Please explain your requirements in more detail because I don't understand what exactly are you trying to get here. Query looks ok, but it's more important to explain what you want to get as a result (include definition of tables that are being queried).

Comment: The query returns the rows without the effect of the WHERE clause and the $vars are being filled out properly too.

Comment: Simple question: do you know the difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @LightBulb that's a good point, just in case I give a link to the [best the explanation of different JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query itself is correct (although really inefficient due to ORs and % % [ indexes will not be used] ).
I would suggest to echo the query, are you sure that $var is evaluated correctly ? Try to run the query directly in mysql (via phpmyadmin for example or using console).

Comment: The $vars are being inserted correctly(I've checked the query) but the rows output remains unaffected, another thing that bums me is that addedBy is filled out, and, according to my table, it should not return any rows because it's not got the correct string in it.

Comment: I can see you have accepted my answer, I am just curious what was wrong in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that simply you did not set $var value. Then condition e.g. students.telephone LIKE '%$var' will become students.telephone LIKE '%' (always true for not null address), which will match every record of the join , exactly what you are getting.